# Compare Dates But Not Times

Tags: date, powershell, compare

How to compare Date and ignore time? I have 2 same dates but different time. I just need to compare the date and ignore the time but `-gt` operator including time. Here is the code.

```psh
if((get-date $Date1) -gt (get-date $Date2))
{
  // do something.
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `.Date` property of your datetime objects:

```
if((get-date $Date1).Date -gt (get-date $Date2).Date)
{
  // do something.
}
```

Per the comments:

```
$date1 = '08/25/2015 00:00:00'
$date2 =  '08/25/2015 12:00:00 AM'

if((get-date $Date1).Date -gt (get-date $Date2).Date)
{
  '$Date1 is greater than $Date2'
}

else { '$Date1 is not greater than $Date2'}

$Date1 is not greater than $Date2
```

Reversing the values:

```
$date1 = '08/25/2015 12:00:00'
$date2 =  '08/25/2015 00:00:00 AM'

if((get-date $Date1).Date -gt (get-date $Date2).Date)
{
  '$Date1 is greater than $Date2'
}

else { '$Date1 is not greater than $Date2'}

$Date1 is not greater than $Date2
```

Comment: Still not working. It should ignore the following record but it's picking up. Date1 is the first value and Date2 is the second value .     08/25/2015 00:00:00 - 8/25/2015 12:00:00 AM

Comment: It's really weird that I had to close the Powershell window and open a new one. After that your code started working. Thank you so much. I appreciate it.